# How do I create a NextGen slideshow to show all photos?

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

I have tried many plugins to create a slideshow out of photos I have uploaded to my NextGen galleries. Specifically, I want this slideshow to incorporate photos from all of my galleries. However, so far, the plugins I have encountered only allow for the photos in the slideshow to come from one gallery (as specified by an id argument).

How do I do create a slideshow that has all of my photos in all of my NextGen galleries? I have assigned a tag to each of my photos in NextGen if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the nextgen gallery slideshow widget you will find the option "select gallery" => "all images".